# hibernate criteria filter objects by list

Tags: hibernate, criteria

how can i filter out some entities by a list of them, i tried the following, but i get could not resolve property: entity of: MyEntity:

```
    public List getEntities(Set<MyEntity> blockedEntities) {
            Session session = getCurrentSession();
            Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(MyEntity.class, "entity");
            crit.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("entity", blockedEntities)));
            return (ArrayList<MyEntity>) crit.list();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the IDs:

```
crit.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("entity.id", idsOfTheBlockedEntities)));
```

Also, you shouldn't cast the result to `ArrayList<MyEntity>`, but to `List<MyEntity>`.